# Error %d format , not list

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

any help please

I have this code (odoo 10)

```
email_from_ids = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].search(self, [('key', '=', 'auto_backup_from_email_Id')])
```

I have  this error

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

I d'ont understand what mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
email_from_ids = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].search([('key', '=', 'auto_backup_from_email_Id')])
```

without the `self` varibale in the search method. I hope this help you.